# How to delete specific rows in a sql table

Tags: sql, sql-delete

I am new to SQL and I was looking at the DELETE keyword. I want to know how can I delete multiple rows in one go. Eg I want to delete CategoryID 2,3,5. I am trying

```
DELETE FROM Categories
WHERE CategoryID="2"AND CategoryID="3" AND CategoryID="5";
```

but no rows and deleted. And if I use OR then everything gets deleted.

Table name Categories

```
 CategoryID   CategoryName          
   1           Beverages         
   2           Condiments        
   3           Confections       
   4           Dairy Products    
   5           Grains/Cereals    
   6           Meat/Poultry
```

Comment: Just to add to make you things more clear. You get nothing deleted with the AND because there is no row that at the same time is category 2,3 and 5. Sql checks row by row, and that condition(being category 2,3 and 5 at same time) none of the rows comply it. Thats why in this case you have to use the IN keyword.

Comment: Double quotes are for identifiers, i.e. in your DELETE "2" means a column named 2. Use single quotes for string literals, and no quotes at all for integer literals.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `IN`:

```
DELETE FROM Categories
WHERE CategoryID IN (2, 3, 5);
```

Answer (score 0):

In your query case,

```
DELETE FROM Categories
WHERE CategoryID="2"AND CategoryID="3" AND CategoryID="5";
```

there is no row with the data with same category id as 2,3,5.
So you can use 'IN' for getting the respective rows.(3 rows from your data)

Comment: You forgot the solution part. (Same as Gordon Linoff's anyway...)

Comment: `"2"` is a column name in SQL, not a number. Numbers don't need _any_ quotes, and character values need single quotes `'2'`

Comment: so in SQL we should use single quote is that what you are saying? @a-horse-with-no-name

Answer (score 0):

USE 'OR' instead of 'AND' since it is a logical error -
you cannot have ID as 2 AND 3 AND 5
it has to be **ID=2 OR 3 OR 5**

`DELETE FROM Categories WHERE CategoryID="2"OR CategoryID="3" OR CategoryID="5";`